# Mixed results on google places autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have this code

```
    var input, defaultBounds, autocomplete_normal;
    input = (document.getElementById('search_location'));
    defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(-90, -180),
        new google.maps.LatLng(90, 180)
    );
    var options = {
        bounds: defaultBounds,
       types: ['(cities)']
    };

    autocomplete_normal = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete_normal, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete_normal.getPlace();  
        console.log(place);
    });
```

When i search for "Coimbra, Portugal" the places Api return "Coimbra" as "locality" - as it should.

But if i replace   types: ['(cities)'] with   types: ['geocode'] the "Coimbra" is return as "administrative_area_level_2" and no other info about locality.

The code with types: ['(cities)'] is used on submit page in order to get a city. The code with types: ['geocode'] is used on a search form that in this case will not return correct results since the "locality" variable is blank.

I tried to replace geocode with  '(regions)' but with the same results. Can you tell me why this is happening ? And why this is happening only for certain places ?

Answer (score -1):

Administrative_area 2 are also cities...from their doc :

> administrative_area_level_2 indicates a second-order civil entity below the country level. Within the United States, these administrative levels are counties. Not all nations exhibit these administrative levels.'

Geocoding response do not contain 'cities' and thus they are reverted to administrative_area_2.

Comment: I think you are wrong - geocoding does contain cities - for example "Lisbon","Funchal","Porto" (same country diff cities) is returned as "locality".

Comment: oops I misunderstood the question. Coimbra is both a locality and a municipality in Portugal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coimbra. You can choose which one you want from the autocomplete. Put 'Coimbra' here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete and notice the two choices.

Comment: No matter what you chose, Coimbra or District Coimbra i get similar result ( with no locality). Look at this screencapture with console.log on the place response http://prntscr.com/aghl88

Comment: I think this is happening in the cases where the city name is the same as the region name.